# How do I call `getChild('ItemCost currencyID="GBP"', NS).getValue()` from XML Response in Google Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, xml-parsing, xmlelement

I have no problems with getting standard elements from an XML Response like `getChild('BuyerEmail', NS).getText()`but if there is extra data at the end like this `getChild('ItemCost currencyID="GBP"', NS).getValue()` then my code fails with a NUL.  Its seems its the  **`currencyID="GBP"`** which is the problem?!?!

What am I doing wrong?

**Code Snippet:**

```
  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var NS = XmlService.getNamespace("urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
   
  var ack = root.getChildText('Ack', NS);
  var time = root.getChildText('Timestamp', NS);
  var version = root.getChildText('Version', NS);
  var build = root.getChildText('Build', NS);
  var shortmessage = root.getChildText('ShortMessage', NS);
  var longmessage = root.getChildText('LongMessage', NS);
 
  var sr = root.getChildren('SaleRecord', NS);    
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sr.length; i++) {
      
    var orderids = sr[i].getChildren('SellingManagerSoldTransaction', NS);
    
    for (var L = 0; L < orderids.length; L++) {      
     
    var srn = orderids[L].getChild('SaleRecordID', NS).getText();

    var sku = orderids[L].getChild('CustomLabel', NS).getText();
      
    var title = orderids[L].getChild('ItemTitle', NS).getText();

    var qty = orderids[L].getChild('QuantitySold', NS).getText();  
        
    var lineitem = orderids[L].getChild('OrderLineItemID', NS).getText();    
   
    var name = sr[i].getChild('ShippingAddress', NS).getChild('Name', NS).getText();
    var pcode = sr[i].getChild('ShippingAddress', NS).getChild('PostalCode', NS).getText();
    var status = sr[i].getChild('OrderStatus', NS).getChild('CheckoutStatus', NS).getText();
    var paidtime = sr[i].getChild('OrderStatus', NS).getChild('PaidTime', NS).getText();
    var shipped = sr[i].getChild('OrderStatus', NS).getChild('ShippedStatus', NS).getText();
    var email = sr[i].getChild('BuyerEmail', NS).getText();
    var price = sr[i].getChild('SalePrice', NS).getValue();
    var totprice = sr[i].getChild('TotalAmount', NS).getValue();
    
    sheet.appendRow([srn, sku, title, qty, price, totprice, lineitem, name, pcode, status, paidtime, shipped, email]);
      
      }
```

**XML Response Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellingManagerSoldListingsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <!-- Call-specific Output Fields -->
  <PaginationResult> PaginationResultType
    <TotalNumberOfEntries> int </TotalNumberOfEntries>
    <TotalNumberOfPages> int </TotalNumberOfPages>
  </PaginationResult>
  <SaleRecord> SellingManagerSoldOrderType
    <BuyerEmail> string </BuyerEmail>
    <BuyerID> string </BuyerID>
    <CashOnDeliveryCost currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </CashOnDeliveryCost>
    <CreationTime> dateTime </CreationTime>
    <DaysSinceSale> int </DaysSinceSale>
    <ItemCost currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </ItemCost>
    <OrderStatus> SellingManagerOrderStatusType
      <CheckoutStatus> CheckoutStatusCodeType </CheckoutStatus>
      <FeedbackReceived> CommentTypeCodeType </FeedbackReceived>
      <FeedbackSent> boolean </FeedbackSent>
      <IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled> boolean </IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>
      <PaidStatus> SellingManagerPaidStatusCodeType </PaidStatus>
      <PaidTime> dateTime </PaidTime>
      <PaymentHoldStatus> PaymentHoldStatusCodeType </PaymentHoldStatus>
      <PaymentMethodUsed> BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType </PaymentMethodUsed>
      <ShippedStatus> SellingManagerShippedStatusCodeType </ShippedStatus>
      <ShippedTime> dateTime </ShippedTime>
      <TotalEmailsSent> int </TotalEmailsSent>
    </OrderStatus>
    <SalePrice currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </SalePrice>
    <SaleRecordID> long </SaleRecordID>
    <SellingManagerSoldTransaction> SellingManagerSoldTransactionType
      <CharityListing> boolean </CharityListing>
      <CustomLabel> string </CustomLabel>
      <ItemID> ItemIDType (string) </ItemID>
      <ItemTitle> string </ItemTitle>
      <ListedOn> TransactionPlatformCodeType </ListedOn>
      <!-- ... more ListedOn values allowed here ... -->
      <ListingType> ListingTypeCodeType </ListingType>
      <OrderLineItemID> string </OrderLineItemID>
      <QuantitySold> int </QuantitySold>
      <Relisted> boolean </Relisted>
      <ReservePrice currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </ReservePrice>
      <SaleRecordID> long </SaleRecordID>
      <SecondChanceOfferSent> boolean </SecondChanceOfferSent>
      <SoldOn> TransactionPlatformCodeType </SoldOn>
      <StartPrice currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </StartPrice>
      <TransactionID> long </TransactionID>
      <Variation> VariationType </Variation>
      <WatchCount> int </WatchCount>
    </SellingManagerSoldTransaction>
    <!-- ... more SellingManagerSoldTransaction nodes allowed here ... -->
    <ShippingAddress> AddressType
      <Name> string </Name>
      <PostalCode> string </PostalCode>
    </ShippingAddress>
    <ShippingDetails> ShippingDetailsType
      <ShippingType> ShippingTypeCodeType </ShippingType>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <TotalAmount currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </TotalAmount>
    <TotalQuantity> int </TotalQuantity>
    <UnpaidItemStatus> UnpaidItemStatusTypeCodeType </UnpaidItemStatus>
  </SaleRecord>
  <!-- ... more SaleRecord nodes allowed here ... -->
  <!-- Standard Output Fields -->
  <Ack> AckCodeType </Ack>
  <Build> string </Build>
  <CorrelationID> string </CorrelationID>
  <Errors> ErrorType
    <ErrorClassification> ErrorClassificationCodeType </ErrorClassification>
    <ErrorCode> token </ErrorCode>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="string"> ErrorParameterType
      <Value> string </Value>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <!-- ... more ErrorParameters nodes allowed here ... -->
    <LongMessage> string </LongMessage>
    <SeverityCode> SeverityCodeType </SeverityCode>
    <ShortMessage> string </ShortMessage>
  </Errors>
  <!-- ... more Errors nodes allowed here ... -->
  <HardExpirationWarning> string </HardExpirationWarning>
  <Timestamp> dateTime </Timestamp>
  <Version> string </Version>
</GetSellingManagerSoldListingsResponse>
```

Comment: I think that in this case, to provide the sample XML data will help users think of the issue and solution.

Comment: @Razz Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question with more information. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you guys. I have updated my post.

Comment: I found that I could instead just use: ItemCost, SalePrice and TotalAmount without `currencyID="GBP"`.  I missed this because ItemCost does not work with or without `currencyID="GBP"`. Both SalePrice and TotalAmount work fine. 

Does anybody know how my code example could be converted to the Array Map Method to speed the processing up?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have some questions for your updated question. 1. In your script, what is `sr`? 2. What is `NS`? 3. In your script, I cannot understand about the end of for loops. 4. When your sample XML data is used, can you provide the output values you expect?

Comment: Apologies, I missed an important part of the code off by mistake but now I have updated it so your questions are now covered.

Output Values: `sheet.appendRow([srn, sku, title, qty, price, totprice, lineitem, name, pcode, status, paidtime, shipped, email]);`

Comment: @Razz so your initial problem was resolved? Can you post an answer? And "Does anybody know how my code example could be converted to the Array Map Method to speed the processing up?" may be better asked in a new question as it could get  more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could instead just use: ItemCost, SalePrice and TotalAmount without `currencyID="GBP"`.  I missed this because ItemCost does not work with or without `currencyID="GBP"`. Both